# QuickFixN isn't sending logon for trading sessions

Tags: c#, quickfixn

I'm connected to a couple of providers, both Quote and Trade sessions.

The Quote sessions are working fine, but for the Trade sessions the event log looks like this:

```
20180925-06:47:16.131 : Connection succeeded
20180925-06:47:46.463 : Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port yyyyy
20180925-06:47:46.479 : Connection succeeded
20180925-06:48:16.926 : Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port yyyyy
20180925-06:48:16.926 : Connection succeeded
20180925-06:48:47.354 : Connecting to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx on port yyyyy
20180925-06:48:47.354 : Connection succeeded
```

and my message log just has a logOUT at the end

```
20180925-06:50:37.241 : 8=FIX.4.29=6435=534=91249=aaaaaaa52=20180925-06:50:37.24156=bbbbbbb10=145
```

I think Logon messages are generated automatically by QuickFix upon conenction?

What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because of your session settings. When fix server rejects your session details you see logout message.

Logon messages is generated by quickfix lib automatically. I have faced almost same problem and it was about quickfix settings.

Firstly check your sender/target comp id and other session details in config file. If it works for one session and does not work for another, it is related with your settings or fix server has some issues.